# Export as ,DXF fle

Tags: qgis, dxf

I am trying to export a QGIS 3.6.2 file as a .DXF and receive an 'export failed' notification with no details. Export as .PDF and .JPG are successful

Comment: DXF is a  vector format for CAD, JPG is raster format, and PDF can contain both rasters and vectors. What kind of data are you trying to export?

Comment: Are you trying to export a single layer using Save Features As, or using the Project > Export Project as DXF option?